# Apache htaccess ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, errordocument

When I include this if statements in my htaccess file, apache throws Internal Server Error 500:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /custom_50x.html
ErrorDocument 502 /custom_50x.html
ErrorDocument 503 /custom_50x.html
ErrorDocument 504 /custom_50x.html

<Files "custom_404.html">
    <If "-z %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}">
        RedirectMatch 404 ^/custom_404.html$
    </If>
</Files>

<Files "custom_50x.html">
    <If "-z %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}">
        RedirectMatch 404 ^/custom_50x.html$
    </If>
</Files>
```

What could be the reason?

The other problem with Apache is that even if a 404 webpage is added to ErrorDocument 404 directive, the status code which the server sends is 200 instead of 404.

The ErrorDocument 50* directives are not working also. Although I have set custom error pages for them, Apache still shows the default errors.

Comment: What's wrong with only using the ErrorDocument directives? Are you trying to return 404 if the user tries to access the error page directly? I think it's pointless.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it but I don't get it why even the status codes are not working even though the appropriate page is shown for 404. I have to use php header to set the status code.

Comment: Why speculate about the reason when there's an ErrorLog?

Comment: The log contains this: Invalid command '<If', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Found the reason. It is only available for Apache 2.4+. But I still don't know why Apache throws status code 200 for ErrorDocument 404 page.